# Creating table which changes a column in order to remove repeated values in rows

Tags: c#, mysql, database, entity-framework, linq

Sorry if the title was confusing.

Currently I am practicing with Entity Framework and LINQ expressions and got stuck on this.

I have a table with columns:"Personal ID", "Name", "Surname", "Phone ID" and all values on Phone ID are unique. I would like to create another table in which there would be same columns except for last being "Phone Count" which shows how many phones are associated with same Person(Personal ID). I want the table to show only 3 first highest count rows.

Here is the code i've wrote to make table that i've described above.

```
        using (var db = new PRDatabaseEntities())
        {
            var query = from a in db.Person
                        join t in db.Repairs on a.PID equals t.Repairman_PID
                        orderby a.PID
                        select new
                        {
                            a.PID,
                            a.Name,
                            a.Surname,
                            t.Phone_ID
                        };
        }
```

Comment: I think you no need new table.
You can just group by "Personal ID" and select count of  "Phone ID"

Comment: In SQL I would use group by...
select top 3 A, B, C, count (D)
from LETTERTABLE
group by A, B, C
I leave it up to someone else to convert that to Lync

Comment: Is there an one-to-one relationship between `Person` and `Repairman`?

Comment: @Shpionus then how to change it?

Comment: Then you don't have to use `Person` in your query.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan I use it to show not only repairman's ID but also his name and surname. Only Person table has those values.

Comment: Actually, db.Repairman is redundant. Person is needed for Name and Surname, while PID exists in all three tabels (PID is the glue for all tables). And in select `k.PID` should be replaced with `a.PID`.

Comment: sorry, I mean `Repairman` .

Comment: @Jure thanks for that, i'll edit my code a bit

Comment: @HamletHakobyan yea, i'll edit my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try with following group by LINQ query:

```
// First, generate a linq query
var query = from a in Persons
            join t in Repairs on a.PID equals t.Repairman_PID
            group new { a, t } by new { a.PID, a.Name, a.Surname } into g
            select new
            {
                PID = g.Key.PID,
                Name = g.Key.Name,
                Surname = g.Key.Surname,
                PhoneCount = g.Count()
            };

// Then order by PhoneCount descending and take top 3 items
var list = query.OrderByDescending(t => t.PhoneCount).Take(3).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
using (var db = new PRDatabaseEntities())
{
    var query = db.Person
                  .GroupJoin(db.Repairs,
                             p => p.PID, r => r.PID,
                             (p, r) => new {
                                               PID = p.PID,
                                               Name = p.Name,
                                               Surname = p.Surname,
                                               Count = r.Count()
                                           };
}
```

Comment: Well there is a problem with that, it shows count for all person rows, not only for repairman ones.

Comment: But you say that there is one-to-one relationship between `Person` and `Repairman`. Do you have `Person` which hasn't associated `Repairman`?

Comment: Yea, i've propably mistaken, there are more than repairmen in person table